# How can you save a users input in an app

Tags: xcode, storage, storing-data

I am creating an app based on the functions of tinder.... if you like the word (created from a random generator) you swipe right and it stores it in a word bank for the user to go back to later on.

I am very new to Xcode and swift, What is the best way to go about storing the users input within the app?
[Image of the layout of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dsXu.png)

Comment: There are 2 ways to do this; NSUserDefaults or CoreData.

If you only have one user, NSUserDefaults should work. [This Link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults) should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults`.

```
// Set
// forKey is the unique value to access the object you have saved
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("value", forKey: "key")

// Get
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("key")
```

So for example, when you want to save a variable called "score", do:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(\(score), forKey: "key")
```

When you want to get this value:

```
let score = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("key")
```

There are several different types of defaults you can use, I have used `setObject` in this example.